# Jquery autocomplete передача переменной

Tags: jquery, php

jquery autocomplete передача переменной для автозаполнения полей
не могу разобраться как правильно это сделать.
нужно передать id чтобы выполнить автоподбор

```
<input class="mete" id="39" name="chars[39]" value="" type="text">
<input class="mete" id="40" name="chars[40]" value="" type="text">
<input class="mete" id="41" name="chars[41]" value="" type="text">
...

$(function() {
    $(".mete").autocomplete("search.php")       
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос

```
$(".mete").each(function () {
     var $that = $(this);
     $that.autocomplete({source: "search.php?id=" + $that.attr('id')});
});
```

А уже на стороне PHP получать эти значения в массиве $_GET

Comment: Да вопрос понят правильно, но все равно не работает

только если передавать в явном виде

$(".mete").autocomplete("search.php?id=39")

Comment: попробуйте заменить строчку:

$that.autocomplete("search.php?id=" + $that.attr('id'));

Comment: тоже не работает

и даже так
$(".mete").each(function () {
     var $that = $(this);
     $that.autocomplete("search.php?id=39"));
});

Comment: вы уверены, что не опечатались? получается противоречие, что код

    $(".mete").autocomplete("search.php?id=39");

работает, а код

    $(".mete").each(function () {
        var $that = $(this);
        $that.autocomplete("search.php?id=39");
    });

т.к. выполняется то одно и то же.

Comment: Решил задачу так
<code>
$(document).ready(function(){

function ac(id) {
 $('#' + id + '').autocomplete("search.php?a=" + id + '');
}

$(".mete").click(function () {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");  
  ac(id);
});

});
</code>